# Finding VERY precise percentiles based on Z-Scores in C/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, math, statistics

I am creating a program that needs to find thousands of individual percentiles, most of which are less than .00005. Currently, to do this I use

0.5 * erfc(-zScore * M_SQRT1_2)

However, this seems to be rounding slightly (throughout the rest of my program I am using doubles and long doubles, so it has to be this). I believe this because at the end, when I add up all the percentiles, I get 1.835468. This tells me that it is rounding as it should add up 1, or at least a number very close to 1. In addition, when I log each individual percentile, I get the same number (let's say 0.000036) for a few percentiles, and then it goes down to 0.000035. It should be going down each time as each number is further from the mean than the last.

I need a way to find very precise percentiles based on Z-Scores, which this is not giving me as it is rounding too early, at the 6th decimal place.

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement, kindly elaborate with example.

Comment: I edited the post. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I am not getting, but one thing i got that you are facing some problem of rounding. So why to work with 6 decimal digits. multiply each number by 100000 and use it with long. and at last divide them and find your final result.

Comment: Thanks I'll go try that. I think that'll work. If not I'll get back to you and edit the post some more.

Comment: Floats and doubles have natural inacuraccy because of the way they work. You need some sort of BigDecimal class that promices better accuracy.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe more detailed what you calculate and which sum you expect to be 1.0. A small self-contained example program would be the best.

Comment: I would like to emphasize the comment of Martin R. Why do you expect the sum to be 1? `erfc` calculates something related to the probability that a sample has near (or away from) the mean. The sum of a set of such probabilities is not inherently 1, because the events they are probabilities for are not a partitioning of the event space (the intersections of pairs of events are not empty, and the union of all the events is not the entire space). You should show a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/). Additionally, rounding errors in floating point do not explain this.

Comment: Hi. Everything is now working as I changed everything to long doubles, and have fixed the tokens in NSLog. It should add up to 1 (and did) because I was finding the probability of spaces on the normal distribution curve, and each space was added, so ultimately it should add up to the total probability which is 1. I didn't make it clear in the question but I was subtracting one probability from another to find the space between them.

Comment: So the accuracy of `erfc` is irrelevant to you problem, it could have been any function. You compute a lot of differences (of small numbers) and then add all the differences again.

Comment: I voted to close this as incomplete. No code has been provided, and the purported errors of operations on small numbers cannot explain the claimed observation. Adding and subtracting a trillion `double` numbers under 2, each of which is off by 100 ULP (due to a bad math library), would produce an error less than .05, not the .83 that is stated. No information useful to other people has been presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see it jump from 0.000036 to 0.000035, this is because you need to use `NSLog(@"Value is: %0.36f", yourPercentile);`.  You should find that it is not actually rounding at 6 digits, but that was just how it was logged.

Now, your error is coming from the fact that you are using doubles, which do not store precise values very well.  First, you need to know how much precision that you **need**, and then use a type which can handle that level of precision.

Let's say that you decide that you require 12 digits of precision.

long long is then a good unit to use because it can store 19 digits.  When you calculate your original value, you need to multiply the **original** values by 100,000,000,000 and store them as long long's.  Then do the math that you need using the large values.  Eventually, when you get your result, just divide by the same value (or 2 digits less less if you want to see it as a whole number) to get your percentage.

Comment: This is inconsistent with the problem statement. The question says that thousands of values are summed. Even if every result of the `erfc` function is off by 10 ULP of the function’s maximum value, 2, and every addition to the sum rounds by the worst possible amount, 1/2 an ULP of 2, the total error for 10,000 values is less than 5e-11, using 64-bit binary IEEE 754 floating point. Rounding errors, `double`, and inaccuracies in the `erfc` function do not explain the reported observations.

Comment: This answer is similar to what i proposed... but i got downvote... :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Yeah, I'm not sure why.  I was working on my answer at the same time as yours and it was pretty much the same, only I provided more details.  Yours certainly should not have been downvoted though....

Comment: I deleted my answer, sad :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Actually, someone (probably the same person) down-voted my answer too.  It wasn't just you!

Comment: @lnafziger : is there any way we can inform SO-admin/moderator that whenever some one downvotes, a comment has to be there. And if 3 or 5 people are not satisfied with that comment that downvote can be rollover. As in Wikipedia.

Comment: Well, you can suggest it in meta, and without looking I would guess that it has been discussed before.  In this case though, it is very possibly related to the first comment here even though the person asking the question has said this helped.  In any case, it's only -2 points and there will often be people who disagree so I wouldn't sweat it too much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a matter of formatting the number: if two values(long double) are very close each other but still different, you will see them equal, specify the format with something like "%.12Lf".

Comment: .12f will decimal upto that will support by float?

Comment: No, that's an attempt, he should try any format and increase the number of decimal digits until he sees the correct representation.

Comment: ` long long doubles` in Obj-C, no way :(

Comment: `long double` is there, which has 16 decimal precision for this you need to use `@"%.16Lf"`.

Comment: Ok, added it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry.. I changed your answer a bit, is it ok?